# how to set base_url in trntv filekit yii2

Tags: file-upload, yii2

I am using trntv filekit in yii2, when I update profile the widget save profile image correctly in storage but save wrong **base_url** in database? var_dump result show following code :

```
    C:\wamp64\www\realestate\frontend\modules\user\controllers\DefaultController.php:72:
array (size=6)
  'path' => string '1/8fxqQhjo7lhtCkMnNDM6mdo2sODCUtVb.png' (length=38)
  'name' => string 'Capture' (length=7)
  'size' => string '33507' (length=5)
  'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  'order' => string '' (length=0)
  'base_url' => string '/source' (length=7
```

but I want to get following

```
base_url' => string 'http://localhost/realestate/storage/web/source' (length=45)
```

How can I change base_url?

Comment: show te code where you are using  the widget ..

Answer (score 1):

```
'fileStorage'=>[
    'class' => 'trntv\filekit\Storage',
    'baseUrl' => '@web/image' // you should assign this way 
    'filesystem'=> ...
    // OR
    'filesystemComponent' => ...    
  ],
```

https://github.com/trntv/yii2-file-kit#file-storage

Comment: Thank you for your answer scaisEdge. I already have checked gitbub details of trntv and I found same solution there but I want to save Images in storage everything is set but `@storageUrl/` is not working for me? How can i set `@storageUrl` actually?

Comment: what is @storageUrl ... .. you  .. don't see this code in your question .. explain better and add the related  code please